# Getting netbeans more eclipse-y

Tags: eclipse, ide, netbeans

I'm a long-time eclipse user looking to use netbeans now that I've tried netbeans out a bit. I mostly like what I see, except there's a few aesthetics missing. Anyone have ideas on if the following are available in NetBeans?:

- Eclipse highlights modified & inserted lines in the left margin / gutter
- Eclipse highlights the currently edited function in the left margin / gutter
- Eclipse highlights TODO / FIXME comments in the right margin

For example:

[alt text http://img507.imageshack.us/img507/5471/forso.png](http://img507.imageshack.us/img507/5471/forso.png)

... any ideas on how I can get Netbeans to do this sort if stuff ?

Comment: I can't see your picture, but aren't you basically describing the error stripe (on the right margin of the editor)?

Comment: @mmyers : yes - the error stripe in eclipse shows pretty much everything the netbeans one does, plus it hilights comments tagged with TODO & FIXME (which helps me out when starting to code stuff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project is connected to source control netbeans will show added lines with a green block at the beginning of the line, modified lines with a blue block, and deleted lines with a red arrow. It also marks these in the right margin/gutter. This is based off of compared to last commit, not last save however.

As for the other two I could not find a way to implement them but I may just be missing something

Comment: this does fix my #1 'issue' with netbeans, plus I like that it compares against the repository instead of the disk file - thanks :-)

Comment: No problem, I recently switched (about 5 months ago) from eclipse to netbeans, it took awhile to get used to the differences but I prefer it now